# Swift 3: Programmatically functioning scope bar

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

I've set up a search bar to my table view programmatically and added a scope bar to the search bar. I'm trying to figure out how to display the correct information when the user taps one of the scope button. For example, if they tap the "Sweet" scope button, it only displays all the fruits associated with sweet from the data model. This is my code so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
@IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

var fruits = [Fruits]()
var filteredFruits = [Fruits]()
var selectIndex: IndexPath = IndexPath()
var fruitName: String!
var myArray = ["All", "Sweet", "Fresh", "Other"]
var sweets = [String]()

var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    fruits = [
        Fruits(category: "Fresh", name: "Apple"),
        Fruits(category: "Fresh", name: "Strawberry"),
        Fruits(category: "Sweet", name: "Mango"),
        Fruits(category: "Sweet", name: "Cherry"),
        Fruits(category: "Sweet", name: "Grapes"),
        Fruits(category: "Other", name: "Orange"),
        Fruits(category: "Sweet", name: "Banana"),
        Fruits(category: "Fresh", name: "Tomatoe"),
    ]

    myTable.delegate = self
    myTable.dataSource = self

    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Sweet", "Fresh", "Other"]
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    myTable.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white



}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        return filteredFruits.count
    }

    return fruits.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    fruitName = fruits[indexPath.row].name
    let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)
    let fruit: Fruits
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
        fruit = filteredFruits[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]
    }

    if fruits[indexPath.row].category == "Sweet"{
     sweets = [fruits[indexPath.row].category]
        print(sweets)

    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = fruit.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = fruit.category


    return cell
}

//SearchBar
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
    filterContentsforSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)

}

func filterContentsforSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All"){
    filteredFruits = fruits.filter { fruit in
        let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (fruit.category == scope)
        return categoryMatch && fruit.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    }
    myTable.reloadData()
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    filterContentsforSearchText(searchText: searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])

    if selectedScope == 1{
        print("Sweet")
    }

}



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let update the `filterContentsforSearchText` method. You should return `categoryMatch` immediately if the `searchText` is empty:

```
func filterContentsforSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All"){
    filteredFruits = fruits.filter { fruit in
        let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (fruit.category == scope)
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            return categoryMatch
        }
        return categoryMatch && fruit.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    }

    myTable.reloadData()
}
```

Then, remove all `searchController.searchBar.text != ""` statements, you don't need them any more.

The final code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

    var fruits = [Fruits]()
    var filteredFruits = [Fruits]()
    var selectIndex: IndexPath = IndexPath()
    var fruitName: String!
    var myArray = ["All", "Sweet", "Fresh", "Other"]
    var sweets = [String]()

    var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        fruits = [
            Fruits(category: "Fresh", name: "Apple"),
            Fruits(category: "Fresh", name: "Strawberry"),
            Fruits(category: "Sweet", name: "Mango"),
            Fruits(category: "Sweet", name: "Cherry"),
            Fruits(category: "Sweet", name: "Grapes"),
            Fruits(category: "Other", name: "Orange"),
            Fruits(category: "Sweet", name: "Banana"),
            Fruits(category: "Fresh", name: "Tomatoe"),
        ]

        myTable.delegate = self
        myTable.dataSource = self

        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Sweet", "Fresh", "Other"]
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        myTable.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchController.isActive {
            return filteredFruits.count
        }

        return fruits.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        fruitName = fruits[indexPath.row].name
        let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let fruit: Fruits
        if searchController.isActive {
            fruit = filteredFruits[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]
        }

        if fruits[indexPath.row].category == "Sweet"{
            sweets = [fruits[indexPath.row].category]
            print(sweets)

        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = fruit.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = fruit.category


        return cell
    }

    //SearchBar
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
        filterContentsforSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)

    }

    func filterContentsforSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All"){
        filteredFruits = fruits.filter { fruit in
            let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (fruit.category == scope)
            if searchText.isEmpty {
                return categoryMatch
            }
            return categoryMatch && fruit.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }

        myTable.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        filterContentsforSearchText(searchText: searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])

        print("selectedScope: \(selectedScope)")
        if selectedScope == 1{
            print("Sweet")
        }

    }
}
```

And it's working as you expected!

[image]

Comment: Your method works!, however i had one small issue.
for example, the table view has 8 items on it. if i use the scope to filter the last four items it shows the last four items correctly, however when i click on the cell, it displays information for the first four items instead. Is there an additional way for me to have the correct information displayed when the view controller segues?

Comment: You should use the method `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` and retrieve the selected fruit as same as in the method `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. Now, you have a correcly fruit's information. You can perform a segue or do something by passing that fruit.